# using aria for expandable items

Tags: javascript, html, css, wai-aria

I have a expandable `div` element which is expanded when user clicks.
How can i make it accessible through screen readers.
Below is my code

HTML

```
    <div class="expandable" (click)="expandItem()" attr.aria-expanded="isCollapsed">
    Some content to show on expand
</div>
```

JS:

```
expandItem() {
  this.isCollapsed = true
}
```

variable `isCollapsed` is set to false initially.

Comment: You need to toggle the content of the ARIA attribute itself as well. https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-expanded_to_indicate_the_state_of_a_collapsible_element

Comment: isCollapsed is set to false initially and then is set to true on click. But still screen reader is not responding as if it is open or closed

Comment: Are you still talking about your JS variable here? What do you think that has to do with ARIA? No screenreader cares for what variables you might have floating around somewhere. You need to set the attribute _on_ the element to the appropriate value.

Comment: I am setting aria attribute sir. It is either true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be showing my javascript ignorance but I haven't seen `(click)="expandItem()"` or `attr.aria-expanded="isCollapsed"` before.  I **have** seen `onclick="expandeItem()"` and `aria-expanded="false"`.  But I'll ignore that aspect for now.

First off, your `<div>` has no semantic meaning so you'll need several ARIA attributes to fix that.  But before you do that, consider the "[First Rule of ARIA Use](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1)", which is essentially to not use ARIA.  Use native semantic HTML elements as your first choice if possible.

I'd need more information on your scenario but consider using a real `<button>` instead of a `<div>`.  It sounds like you might have a "[disclosure widget](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#disclosure)".

If a real `<button>` is **not** used, then your `<div>` will need:

- `tabindex="0"` (to allow keyboard focus to move to it)
- a click handler (for mouse users)
- a keyboard handler (for keyboard users to use <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> to select it)
- a `role="button"` so a screen reader announces the proper semantics
- (I'm assuming your `<div>` has a label)

In addition to that, then you need to resolve your `aria-expanded` issue.  In the onclick of the button (or div), just toggle the value of `aria-expanded`.  Since that attribute is a "[state](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#dfn-state)" (instead of a "[property](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#dfn-property)"), changing its value will be announced automatically by screen readers.

Comment: Thanks. This attr.aria-expand and (click) are in context with angular. Sorry i didn't specify that. But applying role=button solved my issue.